# Collapse a data frame to a unique row

Tags: r

What I'm trying to do is collapse my data frame such that each unique date has the corresponding variables associated with it. Here is a sample of my data as it is right now (fyi: the full data set I'm using is around 300 obs. with different dates):

```
date <- c("10/30/17", "10/30/17", "10/30/17", "10/30/17")
eventcode <- c("14", "14", "14", "14")
eoi145 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0)
eoi140 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
eoi141 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1)
eoi143 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(date, eventcode, eoi145, eoi140, eoi141, eoi143)
View(df)
```

I want to get into this format:

```
date <- c("10/30/17")
eventcode <- c("14")
eoi145 <- c(1)
eoi140 <- c(1)
eoi141 <- c(1)
eoi143 <- c(1)
df <- data.frame(date, eventcode, eoi145, eoi140, eoi141, eoi143)
```

I've tried using cast, melt, and reshape. Can anyone give me a hint as to any packages or techniques to get this accomplished.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach from the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
reduced_df <- df %>%
  group_by(date, eventcode) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(as.integer(sum(.)))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

With output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
#  date     eventcode eoi145 eoi140 eoi141 eoi143
#  <fct>    <fct>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#  10/30/17 14             1      1      1      1
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Appreciate the help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An other way with data table

```
dcast(melt(DT,measure.vars = patterns("^eoi"))[value != 0],date + eventcode ~variable)

       date eventcode eoi145 eoi140 eoi141 eoi143
1: 10/30/17        14      1      1      1      1
```

you melt and take value != 0

```
melt(DT,measure.vars = patterns("^eoi"))[value == 1]
       date eventcode variable value
1: 10/30/17        14   eoi145     1
2: 10/30/17        14   eoi140     1
3: 10/30/17        14   eoi141     1
4: 10/30/17        14   eoi143     1
```

and then go back to broad again with dcast.
The advantage is that it works for almost any situation. Like if you have

```
eoi143 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)

       date eventcode eoi145 eoi140 eoi141 eoi143
1: 10/30/17        14      1      1      1      2
```